# How to Build .exe file from .app file dynamically?

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

I am working with application developed by `Gupta`, this Application is divided by 9 modules, For building .exe file from each .app file, I can do it easily via

> Project > Build

[image]

I am repeating the above steps for each module.

Is there smart way for building all EXEs with one click as one bat file?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build Gupta source code with command line:
If you want to compile to .exe then use

```
cbi63.exe -b "sourcefile" "destinationfile"
```

in your case this is something like

```
cbi63.exe -b "ktonline.app" "ktonline.exe"
```

If you want to compile to .apd use

```
cbi63.exe -m "sourcefile" "destinationfile"
```

This works with all Gupta versions. You just have to adjust cbiXXX.exe to your IDE version (e.g. cbi71.exe).

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, Many Thanks.